# how to access state value in ejs template in a different request

Tags: node.js, ejs

on the server side i have the following

```
const join = async (req, h) => {
  const gState = add(req.payload.id, req.state.player);
  return h.redirect(`/g/${req.payload.id}`);
};
```

how can i access `req.state.player` in another ejs view `/g/${req.payload.id}/c`?

I have tried `<%= req.state.player %>` but it does not work.